# To connect Active GPS Antenna wires on PCBA should Solder or use Connector

Tags: pcb, rf, connector, soldering, gps

Will it make a difference if I solder or use the supplied SMA type connector to connect the wires of Active GPS antenna on PCBA?

I am using gps antenna of this type.
[image: Active GPS Antenna and Connector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely recommend a connector.

If your antenna should break down or you want to use another one, it would be much easier to replace it. Repeated soldering would also cause the PCB to suffer.

Electrically it is also better to use a connector.

Besides all that, your hardware will look more professional if you use a connector.

--edit: Assuming the connector solution and the soldering solution are both perfect, I would say both are electrically equal. I was thinking of the thermo-mechanical stress for the solder joint which could lead to cracks and later to a higher contact resistance. However, since one could now assume that the electrical connection would be equally good, the advantages of the connector solution speaks for itself.

--edit2: I want to add the input of [JRE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/47070/jre): Using an connector ensures a defined impedance whereas a solder connection would have an undefined impedance which may lead to unexpected problems.

Comment: Can you elaborate how a connector is better "Electrically" compared to soldering wires of the GPS antenna?

Comment: Assuming the connector solution and the soldering solution are both perfect, I would say both are electrically equal. I was thinking of the thermo-mechanical stress for the solder joint which could lead to cracks and later to a higher contact resistance.
However, since one could now assume that the electrical connection would be equally good, the advantages of the connector solution speaks for itself.

Comment: Soldering won't deliver the same results as using the connector.  The cable and the connectors have a defined impedance.  When you undo the braid around the central conductor, you change the impedance.  The impedance is then pretty much "anything goes" and can change depending on how the cable lies.  It will vary with motion (moving the cable will change the impedance.)   It will vary with each junction - if you make a bunch of these boards, the impedance will be different for each one.

Comment: The cable are usually fairly stiff, so you will also be in danger of tearing the pads off of the board each time you move the cable.  The connectors are mounted solidly on the board and won't break as easily.

Comment: TLDR:  Use the connector.